# Building Atom text editor on Windows fails

Tags: electron, atom-editor

I assume we can build Atom on Windows
I followed "Hacking on Atom Core" https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/hacking-on-atom-core/#platform-windows

but when I tried to build release 1.59 it failed.

npm ERR! C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\15.9.0\include\node\v8.h(28,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cppgc/common.h': No such file or directory [.\atom_git\atom-1.59-releases\script\node_modules\fs-admin\build\fs_admin.vcxproj]

npm fails to download and install modules.
...
npm WARN old lockfile about: No matching version found for about@1.9.1.
...

I'll really appreciate if somebody can give a reference to Atom build manual.

Thanks.

Comment: You might have more luck asking on the Atom Community Discord server https://discord.gg/VKSrVMNX

Answer (score 0):

I had found that build fails when I follow the instructions.
But it builds if I use apm to load modules and build it.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.